# Nginx logging per site to syslog

Tags: nginx, rsyslog

I'm currently logging each site in nginx using its own access and error log configuration:

```
access_log      syslog:server=localhost,tag=nginx_access_internet,severity=info;
error_log       syslog:server=localhost,tag=nginx_error_internet;
```

This does not scale very well with multiple sites. I'm wondering if there's an easy, scaleable way to log things into a directory structure such as:

```
/var/log/nginx/sites/SITENAME/logfile
```

Comment: did not get your question properly, why are you sending to syslog when nginx directly writes to a file ?

Comment: I'm trying to get all of my logging through syslog - eventually I'd like to be able to pipe it to a different machine, or an online service of some sort. Either way (via syslog or file), is there a hostname replacement of some sort?